# sending bitmap image and ImageView through intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, bitmap, uri

i am developing an application in which i want to send the map location like whats app. in my application i am taking the snap shot of the map that need to be shared to whats app. i am able to take the snap shot and tested by setting it with the image-view to test.bu i am unable to share it to whats app,i am created the uri also.but it is not working please help me to do it

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.watsapp_button:
            takeSnapshot();
            Uri imgUri=Uri.parse("android.resource://com.koteswara.wise.plaeces/"+R.id.screenimage);
            //address = _gettext.getText().toString();

            //String uri = Uri.Builder().scheme("geo").appendPath(latitude +","+ longitude).appendQueryParameter("q", result).build();
            //String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" +latitude+","+longitude;

            /*String uri = "geo:" + latitude + ","
                    +longitude + "?q=" + latitude
                    + "," + longitude;*/
            //Uri imgUri=Uri.parse("android.resource://my.package.name/"+R.drawable.image);
            String uri = 
            "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + latitude + "," + latitude + "&iwloc=A";
            Uri myUri = Uri.parse(uri);
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    //Target whatsapp:
                    shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    //Add text and then Image URI
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, result);

                    System.out.println(result);
                    System.out.println(uri);
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);
                    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                    try {
                        startActivity(shareIntent);
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        //ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Whatsapp have not been installed.");
                    }
            break;
```

below code show taking the snap shot

```
private void takeSnapshot() {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                return;
            }



            final SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                    // Callback is called from the main thread, so we can modify the ImageView safely.
                    _snapshot=snapshot;
                    snapshotHolder.setImageBitmap(snapshot);
                    System.out.println(snapshotHolder+"snap shot ");
                }
            };
googleMap.snapshot(callback);


     }
below is the image view
snapshotHolder=(ImageView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.screenimage);






 Uri imgUri=Uri.parse("android.resource://com.koteswara.wise.plaeces/"+R.id.screenimage);
in the above uri the R.id.screenimage is the id of the imageview i am setting the snap shot of the map-view
```

any one please help me to send the snapshot of the map i took through intent to share with whats app solution will be appreciated in advance

Answer (score 1):

You try converting your image into byte format,then you can pass it through putExtra() method of Intent.

```
 Bitmap snapshot;
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 snapshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
 byte[] temp_photo=stream.toByteArray();
 Intent shareIntent=new Intent();
 shareIntent.putExtra("Image_Key",temp_photo);
```

Comment: gives an error byte[] cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable.

Comment: is there any way to create the Uri using bit map image to pass it through as  shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri);

Comment: how to store the bit map image in to internal storage and take the particular stored image and delete after function is over please give me any sample code if any one have it